# Isotope appended -- in vanilla javascript class style

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, jquery-isotope

I am working on a knockout based application with isotope.

We are using the vanilla method to invoke isotope. Having problems with the appended method.

//need something like this where you just add new items
http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/ECKiw

//our mock code fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/ayve1nmf/30/

```
  // init Isotope
  var Iso =  new Isotope($('.isotope')[0], {
    itemSelector: '.element-item',
    layoutMode: 'fitRows',
    getSortData: {
      name: '.name',
      symbol: '.symbol',
      number: '.number parseInt',
      category: '[data-category]',
      weight: function( itemElem ) {
        var weight = $( itemElem ).find('.weight').text();
        return parseFloat( weight.replace( /[\(\)]/g, '') );
      }
    }
  });
```

So isotope is invoked via a class. How should the jsfiddle be tweaked to get it to invoke other methods like append/appended?

Comment: You should make a custom knockout binding for Isotope, so that you can data-bind the element rather than jQuery-searching for it. I don't see any Knockout in your mock fiddle, though. Do you consider it relevant to your use of Isotope?

Comment: I think I read the docs relating to this - although I've not used knockout much, and just started working on this isotope application part. I would prefer to use the jquery plugin method as I am more used to it. But I am unsure why its not possible to trigger the append method using Iso

Comment: I've written an Isotope binding: https://gist.github.com/mbest/7577891